# How to get the fetched json data to listing in flutter?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter

I am able to successfully fetch JSON data from the server, but not able to decode the data and configure to the required list. How Should I do that?

This is the code I am using to fetch the field data

```
OrderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    error = json['error'];
    if (json['content'] != null) {
      content = new List<OrderContent>();
      json['content'].forEach((v) {

        content.add(new OrderContent.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
```

The json['content'] is  Map<String, dynamic>. In .forEach((v) what should I write to get the data? I am new to this flutter and JSON learning, I think I am wrong at this point only

THE JSON DATA STRUCTURE ON WHICH I AM WORKING IS BELOW

```
{
    "error": "false",
    "content": {
        "16": [
            [
                {
                    "sod_pk": "31688",
                    "soh_fk": "23660",
                    "sqd_fk": "33294",

                    "order_header": {
                        "soh_pk": "23660",
                        "order_no": "16",
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "sod_pk": "31689",
                    "soh_fk": "23660",
                    "sqd_fk": "33293",

                    "order_header": {
                        "soh_pk": "23660",
                        "order_no": "16",
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
       




 "18": [
            [
                {
                    "sod_pk": "31744",
                    "soh_fk": "23702",
                    "sqd_fk": "33354",
                    "order_header": {
                        "soh_pk": "23702",
                        "order_no": "18",
                    }
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "sod_pk": "31745",
                    "soh_fk": "23702",
                    "sqd_fk": "33356",

                    "order_header": {
                        "soh_pk": "23702",
                        "order_no": "18",
                    }
                }
            ],
           
        ]
    }
}
```

the above JSON data structure has the order no nested in every item details, which has to be fetched inside all order numbers, then the respective data of orders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON data fetched from server but showing error when querying fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547657/json-data-fetched-from-server-but-showing-error-when-querying-fields)

Answer (score 0):

First, do not write the decode code by yourself, you should use some tool like [Built_Value](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) to help you handle those stuff.

Second, I think the server response can be improved, like improved into one level array, instead of 2 level array ?

If I understand correct, you can just use the array's item order ?